# Trying to change div content, but Jquery event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change content in the div, when user typing in other div. Everything works fine: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yusr7zn8/)**

But when I insert these divs inside another div (I insert these divs inside HTML-editor that is editable div) - it is not working at all.
How can it block this?

```js
$(document).keyup(function() {
  var add_title = $("#add_title").html();
  $("#title").html(add_title);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=title class=title>default</div>
<div id=add_title class=input contenteditable=true></div>
```

Comment: use event delegation if you do this on dynamic element use `.on()`

Comment: Create another fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Create a fiddle (or use the code snippet here) that shows the issue you are facing. Current jsfiddle doesn't show the issue.

Comment: The issue appears only on my website, when I insert this code inside another div, I can not show it it jsfiddle.

Comment: @DmitryKruchko there might be some conflict with ID's of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.input',function () {
var add_title = $(this).html();
$( "#title" ).html(add_title);
});
```

It seems like you are adding dynamic elements to the page and for those elements it is not working. if that is the issue then you have to look into event delegation a bit more. The above code will hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: Since he has the event bound to `document`, it should work when he types into any element, static of dynamic.

Comment: But if its dynamic he has to use .on(). Right?

Comment: Only if you want to delegate to specific elements like `.input`. If you bind to `$(document)` directly, it always exists. It will respond to typing in any element.

Comment: $(document).on('keyup','.input',function () - not working too

Comment: I figured out. Content of parent <div> was created dynamically. That is why I could not make event work